# Why are coin miners (such as GUIMiner) a "threat" in Windows Defender?

Tags: windows, guiminer, malware

I opened up my GUIMiner and I got a rather unfriendly "Win32/CoinMiner" threat of "Medium."

I installed this program knowingly, so should I be concerned? Is this just a problem because people have been installing miners on people's machine unknowingly (which would be a bad thing)?

Comment: >>people have been installing miners on people's machine unknowingly (which would be a bad thing)? - Correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is because of hackers that bundle the CPU miners in their viruses causing *unaware* AV makers to ban the miners that are being used. (including cgminer due to the fact it was cpuminer)

EDIT: According to nmat, there are also virus GPU miners.

Comment: [Symantec reported](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/bitcoin-mining-trojanbadminer) that some virus already use GPU